# Can't import Render module in Rascal

Tags: rascal

I am trying to import the Render module as described in: http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Recipes/Recipes.html#/Recipes/Visualization/ParseTree/ParseTree.html

```
rascal>import ParseTree;
ok
rascal>import vis::Figure;
ok
rascal>import vis::ParseTree;
ok
rascal>import vis::Render;
|prompt:///|(0,19,<1,0>,<1,19>): Could not import module vis::Render: File rascal://vis::Render not found.
?[Advice](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Errors/Static/ModuleImport/ModuleImport.html)
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you running from the command line, or from inside Eclipse? I ask because I know you were using the command line earlier, but this is only available running inside Eclipse.

Comment: I am running this from the command line. That seems to answer my question. If you want to post an answer I'd be happy for vote for it :)